# Are bundles used to construct or analyze spaces?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I think of bundles as being a generalization of the product. When using a product I can construct new spaces. But the definition of a bundle as a triple $(E, \pi, B)$ requires that I already have a total space $E$ ready. This makes me think that a bundle isn't really a tool for creating new spaces, but for analyze them.

As a quick example, I can construct a möbius strip using quotient spaces, and later on analyze it as a bundle.

Am I right to think of it this way?

Comment: You can certainly create new (vector) bundles from old ones too: Whitney sums, tensor product, quotient bundles, Hom bundles etc. So, your question seems a little vague.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> The distinction between _a tool for creating new spaces_ and _[a tool] for analyz[ing] them_ seems artificial and imposed to me. As peek-a-boo notes, existing bundles can be used to construct new spaces. <> It's important (and probably relevant) to note that the total space $E$ of a bundle _as a space_ is not the same as $E$ _as the total space of a bundle_, the latter being equipped with a mapping $\pi:E\to B$. For example, there exist infinitely many interesting fibre bundles (the _even Hirzebruch surfaces_) with total space $E = S^2\times S^2$ and base space $B=S^{2}$.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not worried about creating new bundles from old ones. I'm confused about why the total space $E$ is an "ingredient" of the bundle. It leads me to think that we use bundles to analyze $E$. But this goes against my understanding of a bundle as a generalized product. Why would I need $E$ as an ingredient if I'm trying to construct it? Should I edit my question to make this more clear?

Comment: When we view a bundle over $B$ as a mapping $p:E \to B$ satisfying conditions, we might simply view $E$ as the domain and $B$ as the codomain; in that sense, a bundle is "really" just the mapping $p$. From a formal perspective, we have to construct or specify $E$ before defining $p$ because a mapping must have a domain. That said, it seems likely these comments miss something crucial in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better comparison, one can describe products in the same language: a product is a collection $(P,\pi_1,\pi_2,X,Y)$, where $\pi_1:P\to X$ and $\pi_2:P\to Y$ are maps satisfying certain axioms. In more category-theoretic settings, this is the standard definition. The key property of products is that the entire collection is determined (up to isomorphism) by $(X,Y)$ alone. For bundles this is not the case: we clearly cannot determine a bundle from the base space alone, and even if we specify the base space and fiber, some additional topological data is needed to uniquely determine the bundle.

That said, this is a somewhat limited view of the role that products play, and even more so for fiber bundles. A bundle isn't just the total space $E$, it is the whole structure $(E,\pi,B)$. They aren't used to analyze spaces which happen to be the total space $E$ of some bundle; rather, they arise naturally when one tries to assign some kind of "local data" to a space, which happens all over topology and geometry: some examples being the tangent bundle of a manifold, the various tensor bundles which arise from it, orientations, covering spaces, and many others besides. Fiber bundles provide a single language with which to describe the common properties of all of these structures.